# What causes Uncaught Errors during PHP PDO Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to do an insert to my MySQL database with PHP PDO. There is my connection code on my connection file located at ../Info/Connection.php

```
<?php
    $user = "InsertDB";
    $pass = "Passwword123";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SQL10', $user, $pass);
?>
```

I am using an insert on another page. Here is the insert code on my form page at ../Events/Add.php

```
<?php
    include "../Info/Connection.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF_8">
</head>
<body>
  <H1>Add Event</H1>
  Add An Event.<br/ >
  <hr />
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST["Submit"])) {
      $EventDate = $_POST['YYYYOfEvent']."-".$_POST['MMOfEvent']."-".$_POST['DDOfEvent'];
      $TodayDate = date("Y-m-d");
      $statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO techdates (DateOfEvent, Event, Assigned, Status, DateOfUpdate) VALUES (:dateofevent, :event, :assigned, :status, :dateofupdate)');
      $statement->execute([
          'dateofevent' => $EventDate,
          'event' => $_POST['Event'],
          'assigned' => $_POST['Assigned'],
          'status' => $_POST['Status'],
          'dateofupdate' => $TodayDate
      ]);
    }
 else {
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

For the prepare line I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in File.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in File.php on line 17.
```

I have never seen this error before but this is preventing the insert. Do I have syntax issue somewhere? I am pretty sure I have connection to my DB without an issue. What do I seem to be missing.

**EDIT**: I have copied the connection information to the Add.php page and now it works. I am wondering if my include statement is missing something. It is as follows.

```
<? php 
include "../Info/Connection.php";
global $pdo;
?>
```

**EDIT2**: Added the updated actual code.

Comment: You do have a missing `'` in `'dateofupdate => $TodayDate]`

Comment: Are you actually including the connection file on the "other page"?  It isn't shown in the code above.

Comment: Sounds like `$pdo` isn't defined properly, which is a sign it didn't get declared like you thought it did.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes sorry that is a typo.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes I am using an include statement to the connection file at the top of the page.

Comment: @tadman Thanks. I will copy my connection string and see if it is making a valid connection.

Comment: @JukEboX  It seems that what you have above is not your _actual_ code.  Could you show us _that_, so we are better informed?

Comment: @PatrickQ You were right about the $pdo statement not being called. Unless my include statement isn't working or my global $pdo isn't working.

Comment: @JukEboX  You don't need to use `global $pdo;` unless it is within a function where `$pdo` isn't passed in as an argument.  Generally speaking, using global vars is discouraged, and even the term "global" is mostly a misnomer in PHP.  The code in `Connection.php` is run in the same scope as whatever file includes it.  I can't really be any more specific regarding your particular case without seeing  the _actual_ code being used, instead of heavily abridged and recreated versions.  TLDR: your use of `global $pdo;` is probably unnecessary and likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks. Looks like the global causing confusions with the connection setting. Please post your comment as the answer and I will make the official answer. :)

Comment: @JukEboX  The question was already closed as a duplicate.  Answers cannot be posted on closed questions.  You might find it helpful to read the PHP manual entry on [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: in your code I see you're initializing $dbh. but using $pdo. could it be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @ursa yeah that was also part of it.